# 'whereabouts' is / are

Tags: grammar

If the sense is plural, I believe we'd use 'whereabouts are', as in '**Their** whereabouts *are* unknown.'

If the sense is singular, we'd use 'whereabouts is', as in '**His** whereabouts *is* unknown.'

Can this be grammatically defended? Are the two examples above grammatically correct?

Comment: If the plural of *"whereabouts"* is *"whereabouts"*, it's perfectly grammatical. Consider *"His itinerary is unknown"* vs. *"Their itineraries are unknown."* And the dictionary says *"whereabouts"* is singular or plural (so *"His whereabouts are ..."* would be grammatical, too).

Comment: When you get that one figured out, see whether you can determine if _cahoots_ is singular or plural.

Comment: whereabouts is/are: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whereabouts+is%2C+whereabouts+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhereabouts%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhereabouts%20are%3B%2Cc0